# Renaming dynamically created controls

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my project, I was dynamically creating panels as per the user input. Each panel has a "Remove button". As the button is clicked the panel should be removed. But in order to hide it/ or delete the panel I need the button-id which is getting named automatically and I was not able to rename it.

```
input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$ctl04" value="Copy PDF and Post Script files!"
usesubmitbehavior="false" EnableViewState="true" type="Button" id="645" name="645" />



addButtonCopyFiles[i].Attributes["id"] = templateId[i].Text;
addButtonCopyFiles[i].Attributes["name"] = templateId[i].Text;
```

This is how I named them, but the name doesn't get replaced. I even removed the "runat", "server" attribute.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: To help make your question a little easier to read, please refrain from posting links/links to images that may prove vital to your question. Links can go bad very quickly. Is it possible that you might be able to put the HTML into your post? Obviously trim it where possible for brevity, to avoid it ending up looking like just a wall of code. Hope this helps, and welcome to SO! :)

Comment: If the button is added dynamically on the server side, its `ID` property can be set.

Comment: @MrAnderson but I'm not using any kind of server-side scripting here

Comment: The `ID` property can be set before the control is added to the page (i.e. you can say `addButtonCopyFiles[i].ID = templateId[i].Text;` before calling `Controls.Add(addButtonCopyFiles[i])`. If it is not set, it is automatically assigned.

Comment: @MrAnderson                                                addButtonCopyFiles[i].Attributes["id"] = templateId[i].Text;
addButtonCopyFiles[i].Attributes["name"] = templateId[i].Text;              
       eachPanel[i].Controls.Add(addButtonCopyFiles[i]);                                    I was doing that but still didnt work

Comment: That's what I mean. Instead of this: `addButtonCopyFiles[i].Attributes["id"] = templateId[i].Text; addButtonCopyFiles[i].Attributes["name"] = templateId[i].Text;`, say this: `addButtonCopyFiles[i].ID = templateId[i].Text;`.

Comment: @MrAnderson this is how I was creating an instance of button ...... Button[] addButtonCopyFiles = new Button[count]; does this might be the issue

Comment: @MrAnderson, thanks!! that worked like a charm!!!

Comment: @chaitanyakrishna no problem! Don't forget to accept the answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ID` property of a `Control` can be explicitly set before it is added to the page.

Replace this code:

```
addButtonCopyFiles[i].Attributes["id"] = templateId[i].Text; 
addButtonCopyFiles[i].Attributes["name"] = templateId[i].Text; 
eachPanel[i].Controls.Add(addButtonCopyFiles[i]);
```

With this code:

```
addButtonCopyFiles[i].ID = templateId[i].Text;
eachPanel[i].Controls.Add(addButtonCopyFiles[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your dynamic creation, set the panel css class to contain the same dynamic ID as the button.  You don't say whether you are removing the panel server or client side, but I'm assuming hiding it client side is enough.

```
addButtonCopyFiles[i].Attributes["id"] = templateId[i].Text;
addButtonCopyFiles[i].Attributes["name"] = templateId[i].Text;

dynamicPanel.CssClass = "dynamicPanel_" + templateId[i].Text;

//jQuery button click event
function removePanel(id){
    $(".dynamicPanel_" + id).hide();
}
```